# Como assinar um PDF digitalmente?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, assinatura-digital

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em PHP com o framework Laravel 5.1 que irá gerar alguns relatórios técnicos, e o cliente quer que esses relatórios sejam assinados digitalmente, ou seja, que conste la no PDF gerado a assinatura eletrônica do responsável técnico.

Não faço a mínima ideia de como funciona isso... Sei que tem uns tokens, cards e etc que são usados para isso, mas como eu puxo essa assinatura pelo meu sistema e coloco lá no documento? Alguém pode me dar uma direção? Existe alguma API ou coisa do tipo?

Comment: Pergunta  interessante +1

Comment: Gratidão pela recompensa :)

Comment: O problema é bastante amplo, assinatura digital tem várias formas e requisitos. Por exemplo, a resposta dada apesar de bem completa, refere-se à assinatura de arquivos em geral, mas não aborda padrões de assinatura específicos de PDF como PADES, que inclusive alteram a estrutura do PDF original e são as mais comumente usadas em assinatura de documentos eletrônicos no padrão ICP Brasil - ainda que a resposta possa ser válida em cenários que aceitem a assinatura 'avulsa', para [a finalidade do site](/help) falta um pouco mais de especificidade na pergunta.

Comment: Vale notar que o fechamento não impede a busca e nem invalida o que já foi postado. O alerta aqui é apenas para esclarecer futuros visitantes.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

## Resposta curta:

1. Obtenha um certificado digital de alguma entidade certificadora (Ex.: SERPRO). Tem que pagar e renovar periodicamente.
2. Use a chave primária do certificado em conjunto com o pdf para criar uma assinatura digital com a função PHP openssl_sign.
3. Grave essa assinatura para um arquivo para vc ou outra pessoa poder testar mais tarde se o arquivo foi assinado por vc com a função openssl_verify.

## Resposta longa:

**Chaves públicas e privadas**

Existem várias formas de se identificar a origem de um determinado arquivo. Uma dessas formas é através do uso de um "par de chaves". Uma chave privada e uma chave pública.
A chave privada é exclusivamente sua e não deve ser entregue a ninguém. A chave pública deve estar disponível ao público em geral.
Os algoritmos que trabalham com este par de chaves, encriptam com a chave privada e descriptam com a chave pública. Desta forma, por a chave privada não ser conhecida, se algum arquivo puder ser descriptografado com a chave pública conhecida de um determinado usuário, temos a certeza que este arquivo veio daquele usuário.
Da mesma forma se encriptarmos um arquivo com a chave pública do usuário somente ele poderá descriptar com a chave privada.

**Hashes**

Outro conceito é a integridade do documento. Garantir que o documento que chega ao destino é exatamente o mesmo da origem. Para isso se calcula o "hash" do arquivo, ou seja, um conjunto de caracteres que representa o arquivo e que tem garantia matemática de ser único para um certo arquivo. O hash do arquivo pode público. Se no destino vc compara o hash do seu arquivo com o hash inicial, vc assegura a integridade do mesmo. Existem vários algoritmos de hash. Um dos
mais comuns é o MD5.

**Assinatura digital**

De forma simplificada, uma assinatura digital nada mais é que um hash criptografado pela chave privada de um usuário.

**Certificados Digitais**

O problema é: quem garante que aquela chave é daquele usuário ? resposta: alguém conhecido por todos. Ou seja uma autoridade certificadora pública. Essas entidades cobram por seus serviços. São como cartórios digitais. Existem várias com preços diferenciados. Elas fornecem os chamados "certificados digitais" que contêm o par de chaves que vc precisa para assinar coisas, para poder se identificar digitalmente entre outras funções.

**Hierarquia de certificados**

Assim um certificado para ser válido tem uma "hirarquia de certificados", ou seja, um outro certificado que valida o seu certificado, outro que valida a entidade que lhe certificou, até chegar à entidade raiz nacional (no nosso caso a ICP-Brasil). Esta hirarquia normalmente tem poucos passos. No máximo uns 4.

**Certificados de servidor**

Além do próprio usuário ter um certificado para si, para que vc possa acessar certificados em um certo servidor, vc precisa habilitar o modo HTTPS. Pra isso o próprio servidor precisa de um certificado para garantir que aquela máquina é realmente a máquina que vc quer acessar. Vc então habilita o modo HTTPS no servidor HTTP de sua preferência, usando o certificado de servidor.

**Meio físico de armazenamento**

Esses certificados podem ser fornecidos de várias formas:

- A1 que são basicamente arquivos que vc próprio pode gravar em um pen-drive ou algo assim e importar diretamente no navegador.
- A3 que são dispositivos de hardware especiais para conter apenas certificados. Parecem um pen-drive, mas têm a função especial de conter certificados em uma memória especial. Existem outras versões que vêm em cartões com a mesma função. A vantangem é que por ser hardware específico são mais seguros do que um certificado presente em um único arquivo, que pode ser apagado ou sustituído facilmente. Neste caso além do custo do certificado existe o custo do hardware.

Se quiser vc pode criar sua própria autoridade certificadora e emitir seus próprios certificados. O problema disto é que vc não tem a segurança de transações que garantem todo o processo e pode ser vítima do famigerado ataque "Man-in-the-middle" se alguém conseguir ficar no meio da origem e destino dos seus dados. Ou seja, sua entidade certificadora
não é conhecida do público em geral e por isso não pode ser garantida a origem dos seus dados.
Normalmente certificadoras desse tipo são usadas apenas para desenvolvimento e os certificados reais são comprados para os servidores de produção.

---

#### Para assinar e verificar um arquivo

Então vamos aos passos de forma mais elaborada:

1. vc precisa obter um certificado digital válido de uma entidade certificadora
2. caso seja um certificado A3 carregue o driver do dispositivo na função "dispositivos de segurança no seu navegador".
3. importe os certificados da sua entidade certificadora na aba "autoridades" da função certificados de seu navegador
4. importe o seu certificado na aba "pessoas"
5. abra o seu certificado e exporte para arquivos a chave pública e privada
6. depois no seu arquivo PHP carregue para uma variável o arquivo PDF e para outra a chave privada
7. depois use a função `openssl_sign` com essas 2 variáveis para criar a assinatura (cheque a documentação)
8. para verificar a assinatura use `openssl_verify` com a chave pública.

#### Para usar certificados digitais em uma aplicação web

1. Siga os passos 1 a 4 acima.
2. Obtenha um certificado digital para o servidor
3. Configure o seu servidor HTTP para usar aquele certificado e habilitar o modo HTTPS
4. Uma vez feito os passos acima, no sistema vc poderá acessar o certificado do cliente através de da variável global `$_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_CERT']`. Vc pode converter o conteúdo dessa variável em um array contendo os dados presentes no certificado (dados pessoais) com o comando `openssl_x509_parse($_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_CERT'])`.
5. As chaves pública e privada podem ser obtidas com os comandos `openssl_get_publickey()` e `openssl_get_privatekey()` respectivamente. Lembre-se que vc só pode obter a chave privada de seus próprios certificados. A chave privada é reservada ao dono do certificado.
6. Depois utilize os passos 6 a 8 do procedimento acima para assinar e verificar um documento.

#### Configurar HTTPS no Apache 2

Coloque em um arquivo (digamos 'cadeiadecertificados.crt') toda a hirarquia de certificados do certificado de servidor. É só copiar e colar um embaixo do outro em um arquivo texto mesmo. Deixe o certificado de servidor em um arquivo separado ('servidor.crt') e a chave privada do certificado do servidor em outro ('servidor.key').

Segue abaixo um modelo de configuração HTTPS no Apache 2

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    Alias /sistema /opt/sistema
    <Directory /opt/sistema>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
        AllowOverride All
        AcceptPathInfo On
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData
    SSLCertificateFile      /opt/sistema/certs/servidor.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /opt/sistema/certs/servidor.key
    SSLCACertificateFile    /opt/sistema/certs/cadeiadecertificados.crt
    SSLVerifyClient require
    SSLVerifyDepth  10

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

#### Criando uma autoridade certificadora local e um certificado de servidor assinado localmente

O script Bash (Linux) abaixo cria uma autoridade certificadora para emissão local de certificados.

- certifique-se que o pacote openssl está instalado. Caso não esteja instale com `sudo apt-get install openssl` (distribuições debian), ou comando correspondente em sua distribuição.
- coloque o código abaixo em um arquivo com nome "openssl.cnf" e mantenha este arquivo na mesma pasta dos scripts abaixo.

arquivo openssl.cnf:

```
#
# OpenSSL example configuration file.
# This is mostly being used for generation of certificate requests.
#

# This definition stops the following lines choking if HOME isn't
# defined.
HOME            = .
RANDFILE        = $ENV::HOME/.rnd

# Extra OBJECT IDENTIFIER info:
#oid_file       = $ENV::HOME/.oid
oid_section     = new_oids

# To use this configuration file with the "-extfile" option of the
# "openssl x509" utility, name here the section containing the
# X.509v3 extensions to use:
# extensions        = 
# (Alternatively, use a configuration file that has only
# X.509v3 extensions in its main [= default] section.)

[ new_oids ]

# We can add new OIDs in here for use by 'ca', 'req' and 'ts'.
# Add a simple OID like this:
# testoid1=1.2.3.4
# Or use config file substitution like this:
# testoid2=${testoid1}.5.6

# Policies used by the TSA examples.
tsa_policy1 = 1.2.3.4.1
tsa_policy2 = 1.2.3.4.5.6
tsa_policy3 = 1.2.3.4.5.7

####################################################################
[ ca ]
default_ca  = CA_default        # The default ca section

####################################################################
[ CA_default ]

dir     = .         # Where everything is kept
certs       = $dir/certs        # Where the issued certs are kept
crl_dir     = $dir/crl      # Where the issued crl are kept
database    = $dir/index.txt    # database index file.
#unique_subject = no            # Set to 'no' to allow creation of
                    # several ctificates with same subject.
new_certs_dir   = $dir          # default place for new certs.

certificate = $dir/cacert.pem   # The CA certificate
serial      = $dir/serial       # The current serial number
crlnumber   = $dir/crlnumber    # the current crl number
                    # must be commented out to leave a V1 CRL
crl     = $dir/crl.pem      # The current CRL
private_key = $dir/private/cakey.pem# The private key
RANDFILE    = $dir/private/.rand    # private random number file

x509_extensions = usr_cert      # The extentions to add to the cert

# Comment out the following two lines for the "traditional"
# (and highly broken) format.
name_opt    = ca_default        # Subject Name options
cert_opt    = ca_default        # Certificate field options

# Extension copying option: use with caution.
# copy_extensions = copy

# Extensions to add to a CRL. Note: Netscape communicator chokes on V2 CRLs
# so this is commented out by default to leave a V1 CRL.
# crlnumber must also be commented out to leave a V1 CRL.
# crl_extensions    = crl_ext

default_days    = 365           # how long to certify for
default_crl_days= 30            # how long before next CRL
default_md  = default       # use public key default MD
preserve    = no            # keep passed DN ordering

# A few difference way of specifying how similar the request should look
# For type CA, the listed attributes must be the same, and the optional
# and supplied fields are just that :-)
policy      = policy_match

# For the CA policy
[ policy_match ]
countryName     = match
stateOrProvinceName = match
organizationName    = match
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName      = supplied
emailAddress        = optional

# For the 'anything' policy
# At this point in time, you must list all acceptable 'object'
# types.
[ policy_anything ]
countryName     = optional
stateOrProvinceName = optional
localityName        = optional
organizationName    = optional
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName      = supplied
emailAddress        = optional

####################################################################
[ req ]
default_bits        = 1024
default_keyfile     = privkey.pem
distinguished_name  = req_distinguished_name
attributes      = req_attributes
x509_extensions = v3_ca # The extentions to add to the self signed cert

# Passwords for private keys if not present they will be prompted for
# input_password = secret
# output_password = secret

# This sets a mask for permitted string types. There are several options. 
# default: PrintableString, T61String, BMPString.
# pkix   : PrintableString, BMPString (PKIX recommendation before 2004)
# utf8only: only UTF8Strings (PKIX recommendation after 2004).
# nombstr : PrintableString, T61String (no BMPStrings or UTF8Strings).
# MASK:XXXX a literal mask value.
# WARNING: ancient versions of Netscape crash on BMPStrings or UTF8Strings.
string_mask = utf8only

# req_extensions = v3_req # The extensions to add to a certificate request

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName         = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default     = AU
countryName_min         = 2
countryName_max         = 2

stateOrProvinceName     = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default = Some-State

localityName            = Locality Name (eg, city)

0.organizationName      = Organization Name (eg, company)
0.organizationName_default  = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd

# we can do this but it is not needed normally :-)
#1.organizationName     = Second Organization Name (eg, company)
#1.organizationName_default = World Wide Web Pty Ltd

organizationalUnitName      = Organizational Unit Name (eg, section)
#organizationalUnitName_default =

commonName          = Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)
commonName_max          = 64

emailAddress            = Email Address
emailAddress_max        = 64

# SET-ex3           = SET extension number 3

[ req_attributes ]
challengePassword       = A challenge password
challengePassword_min       = 4
challengePassword_max       = 20

unstructuredName        = An optional company name

[ usr_cert ]

# These extensions are added when 'ca' signs a request.

# This goes against PKIX guidelines but some CAs do it and some software
# requires this to avoid interpreting an end user certificate as a CA.

basicConstraints=CA:FALSE

# Here are some examples of the usage of nsCertType. If it is omitted
# the certificate can be used for anything *except* object signing.

# This is OK for an SSL server.
# nsCertType            = server

# For an object signing certificate this would be used.
# nsCertType = objsign

# For normal client use this is typical
# nsCertType = client, email

# and for everything including object signing:
# nsCertType = client, email, objsign

# This is typical in keyUsage for a client certificate.
# keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment

# This will be displayed in Netscape's comment listbox.
nsComment           = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"

# PKIX recommendations harmless if included in all certificates.
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer

# This stuff is for subjectAltName and issuerAltname.
# Import the email address.
# subjectAltName=email:copy
# An alternative to produce certificates that aren't
# deprecated according to PKIX.
# subjectAltName=email:move

# Copy subject details
# issuerAltName=issuer:copy

#nsCaRevocationUrl      = http://www.domain.dom/ca-crl.pem
#nsBaseUrl
#nsRevocationUrl
#nsRenewalUrl
#nsCaPolicyUrl
#nsSslServerName

# This is required for TSA certificates.
# extendedKeyUsage = critical,timeStamping

[ v3_req ]

# Extensions to add to a certificate request

basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment

[ v3_ca ]


# Extensions for a typical CA


# PKIX recommendation.

subjectKeyIdentifier=hash

authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer

# This is what PKIX recommends but some broken software chokes on critical
# extensions.
#basicConstraints = critical,CA:true
# So we do this instead.
basicConstraints = CA:true

# Key usage: this is typical for a CA certificate. However since it will
# prevent it being used as an test self-signed certificate it is best
# left out by default.
# keyUsage = cRLSign, keyCertSign

# Some might want this also
# nsCertType = sslCA, emailCA

# Include email address in subject alt name: another PKIX recommendation
# subjectAltName=email:copy
# Copy issuer details
# issuerAltName=issuer:copy

# DER hex encoding of an extension: beware experts only!
# obj=DER:02:03
# Where 'obj' is a standard or added object
# You can even override a supported extension:
# basicConstraints= critical, DER:30:03:01:01:FF

[ crl_ext ]

# CRL extensions.
# Only issuerAltName and authorityKeyIdentifier make any sense in a CRL.

# issuerAltName=issuer:copy
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always

[ proxy_cert_ext ]
# These extensions should be added when creating a proxy certificate

# This goes against PKIX guidelines but some CAs do it and some software
# requires this to avoid interpreting an end user certificate as a CA.

basicConstraints=CA:FALSE

# Here are some examples of the usage of nsCertType. If it is omitted
# the certificate can be used for anything *except* object signing.

# This is OK for an SSL server.
# nsCertType            = server

# For an object signing certificate this would be used.
# nsCertType = objsign

# For normal client use this is typical
# nsCertType = client, email

# and for everything including object signing:
# nsCertType = client, email, objsign

# This is typical in keyUsage for a client certificate.
# keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment

# This will be displayed in Netscape's comment listbox.
nsComment           = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"

# PKIX recommendations harmless if included in all certificates.
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer

# This stuff is for subjectAltName and issuerAltname.
# Import the email address.
# subjectAltName=email:copy
# An alternative to produce certificates that aren't
# deprecated according to PKIX.
# subjectAltName=email:move

# Copy subject details
# issuerAltName=issuer:copy

#nsCaRevocationUrl      = http://www.domain.dom/ca-crl.pem
#nsBaseUrl
#nsRevocationUrl
#nsRenewalUrl
#nsCaPolicyUrl
#nsSslServerName

# This really needs to be in place for it to be a proxy certificate.
proxyCertInfo=critical,language:id-ppl-anyLanguage,pathlen:3,policy:foo

####################################################################
[ tsa ]

default_tsa = tsa_config1   # the default TSA section

[ tsa_config1 ]

# These are used by the TSA reply generation only.
dir     = ./demoCA      # TSA root directory
serial      = $dir/tsaserial    # The current serial number (mandatory)
crypto_device   = builtin       # OpenSSL engine to use for signing
signer_cert = $dir/tsacert.pem  # The TSA signing certificate
                    # (optional)
certs       = $dir/cacert.pem   # Certificate chain to include in reply
                    # (optional)
signer_key  = $dir/private/tsakey.pem # The TSA private key (optional)

default_policy  = tsa_policy1       # Policy if request did not specify it
                    # (optional)
other_policies  = tsa_policy2, tsa_policy3  # acceptable policies (optional)
digests     = md5, sha1     # Acceptable message digests (mandatory)
accuracy    = secs:1, millisecs:500, microsecs:100  # (optional)
clock_precision_digits  = 0 # number of digits after dot. (optional)
ordering        = yes   # Is ordering defined for timestamps?
                # (optional, default: no)
tsa_name        = yes   # Must the TSA name be included in the reply?
                # (optional, default: no)
ess_cert_id_chain   = no    # Must the ESS cert id chain be included?
                # (optional, default: no)
```

Apenas coloque o arquivo openssl.cnf e o script abaixo em uma pasta e rode o script.

```
#/bin/bash

# Este script cria uma autoridade certificadora (CA) local para ser usada 
# em ambientes desenvolvimento e servir como base para emissão de 
# certificados digitais e um certificado de servidor emitido por esta CA. 
#
# São criados os seguintes arquivos:
# rootCA.key => Chave privada da autoridade certificadora local
# rootCA.crt => Certificado da autoridade certificadora local auto-assinado
# server.csr => Solicitação de emissão de certificado de servidor 
# server.key => Chave privada do certificado de servidor solicitado
# server.crt => Certificado de servidor emitido pela autoridade certificadora local
# index.txt e serial são arquivos necessários apenas ao processo de 
# emissão de certificados pelo openssl e não são relevantes para o 
# usuário. Não devem ser apagados mas podem ser ignorados.

echo 00 > serial
touch index.txt

echo "Criar chave privada da Autoridade Ceritficadora (CA)"
openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:123 -out  ./rootCA.key 2048

echo "Remover a senha da chave privada"
openssl rsa -passin pass:123 -in ./rootCA.key -out ./rootCA.key
 
echo "Criar certificado auto-assinado da CA"
openssl req -config openssl.cnf -new -x509 -subj '/C=BR/L=Dev/O=COMPANHIA/CN=CA' -days 99999 -key ./rootCA.key -out ./rootCA.crt

echo "Criar chave privada do servidor"
openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:123 -out ./server.key 2048

echo "Remover senha da chave privada do servidor"
openssl rsa -passin pass:123 -in ./server.key -out ./server.key

echo "Criar requisição de certificado para o servidor"
openssl req -config ./openssl.cnf -new -subj '/C=BR/L=Dev/O=COMPANHIA/CN=server' -key ./server.key -out ./server.csr

echo "Criar certificado para o servidor a partir da requisição de certificado"
openssl ca -batch -config ./openssl.cnf -days 999 -in ./server.csr -out ./server.crt -keyfile ./rootCA.key -cert ./rootCA.crt -policy policy_anything

echo "Apagando arquivos temporários"
rm -f index.txt*
touch index.txt
rm serial.old
rm *.pem

echo "Finalizado."
```

#### Emitindo certificados a partir da autoridade certificadora local

O script abaixo emite certificados a partir da autoridade certificadora criada com o script acima.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Este script emite certificados com base na autoridade certificadora 
# local. É criada uma pasta cujo nome é o nome do dono do certificado, 
# contendo os seguintes arquivos:
# <NOME>.key => Chave privada do usuário
# <NOME>.csr => Requisição de certificado à CA local
# <NOME>.crt => Certificado emitido pela CA local
# <NOME>.p12 => Certificado em formato PKCS12

if [[ -z "$1" || -z "$2" ]]; then
    echo "Uso: emitircertificado <NOME> <CPF>"
    exit
fi

NOME=$1
CPF=$2
DN="/C=BR/L=Dev/O=COMPANHIA/CN=$1:$2"
ARQ="${NOME//[[:space:]]/}"

echo -e "\nCriando pasta... " 
mkdir $ARQ
echo "feito."

echo -e "\nCriando chave privada... "
openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:123 -out ./$ARQ/$ARQ.key 2048
echo "feito."
 
echo -e "\nRemovendo senha..."
openssl rsa -passin pass:123 -in ./$ARQ/$ARQ.key -out ./$ARQ/$ARQ.key
echo "feito."
 
echo -e "\nCriando CSR... "
openssl req -config ./openssl.cnf -new -subj "$DN" -key ./$ARQ/$ARQ.key -out ./$ARQ/$ARQ.csr
echo "feito."
 
echo -e "\nCriando certificado do cliente"
openssl ca -batch -config ./openssl.cnf -days 999 -in ./$ARQ/$ARQ.csr -out ./$ARQ/$ARQ.crt -keyfile ./rootCA.key -cert ./rootCA.crt -policy policy_anything
echo "feito."
    
echo -e "\nExportar o cliente para pkcs12 para importar no navegador"
openssl pkcs12 -export -passout pass:123 -in ./$ARQ/$ARQ.crt -inkey ./$ARQ/$ARQ.key -certfile ./rootCA.crt -out ./$ARQ/$ARQ.p12

echo -e "\nApagar arquivos temporários"
rm -f index.txt*
touch index.txt
rm serial.old
rm *.pem

echo "Finalizado."
```

Espero que seja útil. Fique à vontade para perguntar mais.

Comment: esclareceu bastante @NelsonTeixeira, quando entrar nessa parte do desenvolvimento provavelmente irei perguntar mais sim rs, abraços e muito obrigado!

Comment: Esteja à vontade :)

Comment: Excelente resposta, `+1`!