# É Possível assinar relatórios PDFs no padrão ICP BRASIL 15 com a linguagem PHP?

Tags: php, laravel-5, pdf, assinatura-digital

O cliente quer que os relatórios pdfs em meu sistema sejam assinados digitalmente com padrão ICP BRASIL 15.

**1º Pergunta:**

O PHP sozinho com a função `openssl-pkcs7-sign` assina ICP Brasil 15 ?

**2º Pergunta:**

Observei algumas funções de assinatura digital com PHP. Como por exemplo: a função `openssl-pkcs7-sign`porém muitos consultores dizem que o PHP sozinho não assina ICP Brasil e sim o padrão dele é o tal do RSA.

Alguém poderia me ajudar ? Muito obrigado!

Comment: Veja se essa resposta não responde o que precisa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124828/como-assinar-um-pdf-digitalmente

Comment: Sua segunda dúvida tem fundamento, o link sugerido não supre a necessidade de qualquer tipo de assinatura de PDF, tem casos e casos, e maneiras específicas - revisei o motivo do fechamento para evitar enganos. Sugiro pesquisar por PADES