# Assinar pdf com PHP

Tags: php, pdf, certificado-digital, mpdf, assinatura-digital

Tenho que assinar digitalmente alguns documentos em `PDF`.
Como faço isso em `php`?

---

Qual a extensão que o certificado tem que estar ? 
Estou tendo grande dificuldade de encontrar uma solução se puderem ajudar agradeço.

Comment: Já deu uma olhada nessa pergunta: [como assinar um pdf digitalmente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124828/como-assinar-um-pdf-digitalmente)

Comment: Esta resposta deixou varias dúvidas,

Comment: Eu ja tenho o pdf no caso queria abrir o mesmo e inserir a assinatura? Qual o formato do certificado? Apesar da resposta estar bem completa não me ajudou

Comment: Já tentou usar o [openssl-sign](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php) ?